# Wordpress 4: WPLANG deprecated. How to change language programmatically?

Tags: php, wordpress-4.0

Since WPLANG is deprecated in Wordpress 4, what do you use to set a user selected language?
In versions 3.x.x I used ***define('WPLANG', $lang)*** to set a language and then on the pages could get it using ***get_locale()***. I need to use this approach to differentiate the content for the different languages. I know that it's possible to change the language in Settings->General but I need to do that programmatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. Instead of using    ***define ('WPLANG', $_SESSION['WPLANG']);***    I use    ***$locale = $_SESSION['WPLANG'];***   .

Answer (score 5):

With WordPress 4.0 the define `WPLANG` from `wp-config.php` is - as you have mentioned - depreciated. It has been replaced by an option called `WPLANG` stored in the table `<TablePrefix>_options`.

You could use [`get_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) to access it:

```
$my = get_option('WPLANG','en_US');
```

More details about the change can be found [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/09/05/language-chooser-in-4-0/).

Comment: The code that I used before checked cookies and got language from there, then this language was set in WPLANG and on the pages I used get_locale() to get it. For now I can get a cookie but how to set it for the current user? Should I use update_option()?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that checking cookies and setting WPLANG is done using wp-config.php (require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/set-lang.php');). So in this case I think I cannot use update_option()...

Comment: Question: Is your user logged in into your WordPress based website, or is user meant as everyone who watches that website?

Comment: Everyone who watches the website.

Comment: In that case use a cookie. Updating the option with `update_option()` everytime a user visits the page would stress your database table quite significantly...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of juggling with global variables or constants one could use the filter `locale` to adapt the value on the fly. That would also be more fail-save for future releases.

```
add_filter( 'locale', function( $default_locale ) {
    if ( isset( $_SESSION[ 'WPLANG' ] ) )
        return $_SESSION[ 'WPLANG' ];

    return $default_locale;
} );
```

By the way, `WPLANG` as key in the session is likely at risk to cause a naming collision issue. Keep in mind that other WordPress plugins may also make usage of the global session.

Comment: Wouldnt this require a session_start and a set of WPLANG session elsewhere?

Comment: Sure. I guess I referred to the accepted answer of Alex.